# How to calculate the integral $\int\limits_0^{\infty }\frac{e^{-x}\sin(\pi x)\cos(nx)}{x}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis

How to calculate the integral:

$$I = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty }\frac{e^{-x}\sin(\pi x)\cos(nx)}{x}dx ,$$

Using WolframAlpha, I got the following answer:

$I = \frac{1}{2}(\arctan(n + \pi) - \arctan(n- \pi))$

But I don't understand how we can get such an answer.

Comment: What is $\Pi$? Is it $\pi$?

Comment: @Yuriy  I think the OP used `\Pi` instead of `\pi`.

Comment: Yes I think it is a parameter

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use these two facts:

$\sin a\cos b = \frac 12 (\sin (a+b) + \sin(a-b))$

and

$I(a) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac {e^{-x}\sin ax}{x} dx\\
I' = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x}\cos ax\ dx = \frac {e^{-x}(-\cos ax + a\sin ax)}{1+a^2}|_0^{\infty} = \frac {1}{1+a^2}\\
I(a)-I(0) =\int_0^a\frac {1}{1+a^2}  \ da = \arctan a$

Comment: Nice! I was thinking more along the lines of $\sin 2\alpha=2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha$ but evidently, yours worked just as well!

Answer (score 1):

This is a straightforward integral:  Hint:  Split it into:

$\int\limits_0^\infty \left( {e^{-x} \over x} \right) \sin (\pi x) \cos (n x)\ dx$ and then use integration by parts to find:

$$\frac{1}{2} \left(\tan ^{-1}(n+\pi )-\tan ^{-1}(n-\pi )\right)$$

Comment: You are sure that this is a simple integral, the answer is: $\frac{1}{4}i(Ei(ix(n-\pi + i) - Ei(ix(-n+\pi + i) + Ei(-ix(n+\pi - i) - Ei(ix(n+\pi + i))$, where Ei - Exponential integral. But I don't know how to calculate this within these boundaries.

Comment: @Valzavator There are other ways than calculating the indefinite integral and taking the limits from zero to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Valzavator, first substitute the $\sin(\pi x) \cos(nx)$  with 
$$ \frac{\sin((\pi + n)x) + \sin((\pi-n)x) }{2}. $$

Then also substitute $ e^{-x}$ with $$ \sum (-1)^{n} \frac{ x^{n}}{n!}$$

And now the integral can be solved by using partial integration..